# Can i disable special price for custom customer group and replace with other price

Tags: php, magento, attributes, cart, price

Can i disable special price for some customer role and show new price by role price attribute on product detail. 
(I not using group price but add new attribute for price to this product.)

I want to show price like this example.

**example**

```
product price = 100
product special price = 90
product role price = 80
```

> price  special price  role price = show price

normal user. 
`Y N N = 100`  `Y Y N = 90`  `Y Y Y = 90`  `Y N Y = 100`

role user special price is disable for this role.

`Y N N = 100`  `Y Y N = 100`  `Y Y Y = 80`  `Y N Y = 80`

And how to add to cart with this custom price. 
I add to cart by ajax and `$this->getAddToCartUrl($_product)`

i try to set new price by `$param['price']` on `addAction` in `cartcontroller` before `$cart->addProduct($product, $params);` but it not work this program will add to cart with normal price or special price.